# How could I use SVG icons with the <svg> and <use> tags

Tags: angularjs, svg, salesforce, lds

I have an Angular 1.5 application that communicate with Salesforce using REST API.

Salesforce require us to use SVG icons with the following syntax:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--large slds-icon-standard-user">
    <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#user')}"></use>
</svg>
```

In salesforce does work well.

I'm trying to use locally in order to develop but does not work. I tried the following code:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--large slds-icon-standard-user">
    <use xlink:href="/path/to/the/icon.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

According to this [documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/faq/#how-do-i-display-svg-icons-with-lightning-components) we need to add within the HTML element the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

But no luck! :(

Any idea to use SVG with those tags and refer to a local file?

Comment: What does "no luck" mean exactly?

Comment: Means that the icon is not displayed...

Comment: By "use locally" do you mean testing on your development machine using the `file://` scheme?  If so, if you are testing on Chrome, it may not work due to security features of the browser. Try Firefox instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<img>` and set your `src` reference to the local path of your `.svg` file.

```html
<img class="papa" src="http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg">
```

More here: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Hello ! But it's not possible to change the color of the svg using the <img> tag ?

Comment: @Fitspade No. when using `<img>` with a `.svg` source, the browser will essentially create a rasterized, [png equivalent] version of the resource—editing capabilities are lost. So, if you want to change the colors of the elements inside the svg, you need to use the `<svg>` representation; In that scenario, color changes could be done inline, or with a css selector. 

e.g.:
`<img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg"/>`
versus
`<svg version="1.1" ...>
   <ellipse fill="#C6C6C6" cx="283.5" cy="487.5" rx="259" ry="80"/>
   <path id="bird"  d="..."></path>
</svg>`

Comment: I found the solution, you have to use the "filter" property in css:
HTML: <img class="menu" src="./Icon/menu.svg" />
CSS: filter: invert(28%) sepia(8%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(222deg) brightness(84%) contrast(93%);